# Show that $|\sin(z)|≥1$ at all points on the square with vertices $±(N+1/2)π±(N+1/2)πi $, for any positive integer $ N $.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Show that $|\sin(z)|≥1$ at all points on the square with vertices $±(N+1/2)π±(N+1/2)πi$, for any positive integer $N$.

One of the confusing things is 'at all points on the square with ...'.

I tried $N=1,2,3, ... ,$ then what I find is that $z$ should be all points in $x,y$ plane.

Am I right? or What's wrong with me?

Comment: probably not ... if imaginary part is zero, then  $\sin(z) \le 1$

Comment: Then what I interpret about the problem is wrong? English is my second language, and I am very confusing 'at all points on the square with vertices ...'

Comment: I think yes, for all points in the edge of square, the inequality holds.

Comment: Ah..! Thank you very much !

Comment: use this formula $\sin(x+iy) = \sin(x) \cosh(y) + i \sinh(y) \cos (x)$

Comment: I use $|\sin(z)|^2 \geq 1$, so I get $sinh^2y \geq cos^2x$, then actually no advance..

Comment: $|\sin (x + iy)| = \sqrt{\cosh^2 y \sin^2 x +\sinh^2 y \cos^2 x } $ use $\sinh^2(x) = \cosh^2(x) - 1$ and simplify it further.

Comment: I got $\sqrt{cosh^2y - cos^2x} \geq 1$ and... no advance.. I'm disappointed.. Anyway your reply helps me very much, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\sin(z)| = \sqrt{\cosh^2y-\cos^2 x}$

Along the left and right of a square $x=±(N+1/2)π$ and $\cos x = 0$ so that $|\sin(z)| = \sqrt{\cosh^2y-\cos^2 x}= \cosh y\ge 1$ since the $\cosh$ function is always greater than 1.

Along the top and bottom of a square $y=±(N+1/2)π$ and since $\cosh y$ is an increasing function for positive $y$ and is also an even function,  $\cosh y\ge \cosh \pi/2\ge 2$. Since $|\cosh^2y-\cos^2 x|\ge |\cosh^2y|-|\cos^2 x|\ge 4 -1=3$, we have $|\sin(z)| = \sqrt{|\cosh^2y-\cos^2 x|}\ge \sqrt{|\cosh^2 y|-|\cos^2 x|}\ge \sqrt{3}\ge 1$.